# Accurately measuring small website performance improvements

Tags: performance, minify, http-compression, web-performance

I just minified the HTML of my home page using WebMarkupMin and switched from gzip to deflate (as a result of using WebMarkupMin's `CompressContentAttribute`). This resulted in the original Content-Length of 21594 shrinking to Content-Length:15539. Now I'm trying to measure if this has resulted in a faster load time. I've tried writing down refresh load times from Chrome dev tools and then calculating an average, which has worked fine in the past for bigger changes, but this time the results seem to be too variable to be useful. I've even tried online speed tests like Pingdom. This is a very minor change, but I would like to know definitely if it was worth it (processing time vs. network time). How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a website optimization utility, such as [Rigor](https://www.rigor.com), [Google Site Test](https://testmysite.withgoogle.com), or [Webpage Test](http://www.webpagetest.org/). These will give you some measurement on how quickly your site downloads and loads in the browser.